# Currency Convert issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have class which help to convert usd to inr now which are giving error now which is this:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

On this line code line:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(streamReader.ReadToEnd(), "<span class=\"?bld\"?>([^<]+)</span>")[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Here is a full class:

```
public static decimal CurrencyConvert(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
{
    //Grab your values and build your Web Request to the API
    string apiURL = String.Format("http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a={0}&from={1}&to={2}&meta={3}", amount, fromCurrency, toCurrency, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    //Make your Web Request and grab the results
    var request = WebRequest.Create(apiURL);
    //Get the Response
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    //Grab your converted value (ie 2.45 USD)
    var result = Regex.Matches(streamReader.ReadToEnd(), "<span class=\"?bld\"?>([^<]+)</span>")[0].Groups[1].Value;
    //Get the Result
    return Convert.ToDecimal(result.Replace(" INR", ""));
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What does `streamReader.ReadToEnd()` return? It is the key to why the regex does not match exactly what you what you want and thus there aren't enough matches or groups.

Comment: var result = Regex.Matches(streamReader.ReadToEnd(), "<span class=\"?bld\"?>([^<]+)</span>")[0].Groups[1].Value; I'm getting error here

Comment: Yes, but what does your stream contain? `var str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();` and check `str`'s value.

Comment: `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.`

Comment: It seems that streamReader.ReadToEnd() returns null or empty.

Comment: no it was not null and empty

Comment: var result = Regex.Matches(streamReader.ReadToEnd(), "<span class=\"?bld\"?>([^<]+)</span>")[0].Groups[1].Value;  here i got  bug `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.`

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. You can do so by issuing the request to Google yourself, saving the string in a string variable and show _that_ in your question.

Comment: You have twice been asked what the stream contains.  So far the only information we have about the stream is that it isn't null or empty.  Okay, so to ask a third time, what does it contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are using is incorrect.  It results in a redirect to `http://finance.google.com/finance/` which means that it is not performing the conversion.  If you look at the stream data that comes back, it does not have a matching `span` that would match your regular expression.  If you make your URL `http://finance.google.com` it should work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int amount = 100;
     string from = "USD";
     string to = "INR";
     var result = CurrencyConvert(amount, from, to);
     Console.WriteLine($"Conversion of {amount} from {from} to {to} equals {result}");
}

public static decimal CurrencyConvert(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
{
     //Grab your values and build your Web Request to the API
     string apiURL = String.Format("http://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a={0}&from={1}&to={2}&meta={3}", amount, fromCurrency, toCurrency, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
     //Make your Web Request and grab the results
     var request = WebRequest.Create(apiURL);         
     //Get the Response
     var streamReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
     //Grab your converted value (ie 2.45 USD)
     var streamData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     var result = Regex.Matches(streamData, "<span class=\"?bld\"?>([^<]+)</span>")[0].Groups[1].Value;
     //Get the Result
     return Convert.ToDecimal(result.Replace(" INR", ""));
}
```

Comment: thank you stephen i think thy have changed url before it was working well. can you please let me know how can i know if url is change in future in case

Comment: Hello @stephen.vakil, same issue again facing my I know any solution which will be fixed and not come again